# Adding to values rather than replacing existing values with media queries. CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to target a bunch of selectors with a media query, and ADD to their existing padding value, rather than having to specify a specific number of px, % etc for each. Is this possible?
 e.g.:

```
<div id="1"> blah</div>
<div id="2"> blah</div>
<div id="3"> blah</div>

#1 { padding: 100px;}
#2 {padding: 75px; }
```

.....
 etc

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

#1
#2
#3 {
    padding: +100px; } }
```

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't possible with CSS alone. You'll need a pre-processor like Less or Sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure CSS this isn't possible.

When you use any CSS preprocessor, eg. LESS or SASS, you can use theere variables, do math operations (add 100px to existing one padding etc.).

Comment: Thanks! Any guidance on how to in Sass?

Comment: I prefer LESS, but, Google doesn't work today? http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using CSS.

Take a look at either jQuery or more structured styling options such as SASS. Very powerful and much better than CSS.